# Is there any mechanism in JCE to specify key generation life time (session key or permanent key)

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

I am implementing JCE provider for an HSM

Is there any mechanism in JCE to specify key generation type
ex: session key or permanent key

```
     KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
     keygen.init(128);
     key = keygen.generateKey();
```

I need something like:

```
     key = keygen.generateKey(flag); 
     flag = 0/1 session key/permanent key
     keygen.deleteKey(); //to delete permanent key
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way of specifying a session key or permanent key.

But you could of course define your own `AlgorithmParameterSpec` to be used within an `init` method and implemented in `engineInit` within your `KeyGeneratorSpi` The `AlgorithmParameterSpec` could indicate if something is session key or permanent key, and could *contain* the parameters of the algorithm (i.e. one that specifies the key size for AES) and possible an additional method for retrieving the key size (as there doesn't seem any specific `AlgorithmParameterSpec` for the key size).

You probably should let your provider *default* to session keys; usually the key value is lost unless it is stored in a `KeyStore` or encoded to file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...!

Comment: As indicated, that depends on the provider and the PKCS#11 library used. The Oracle proder could forget to set the right PKCS#11 attribute to create a session key. I went as far as creating my own provider for this (never finished, company stopped it). I'll try and see what happens when I'm back at work.

Answer (score 0):

JCE frame-work is not developed by keeping in the view of H/W token requirements

I found a work around:

Generating all the keys as token keys(permanent) and maintaining references of key handles in a hash table

my JCE provider has a shutdown function, which will be invoked when application terminates.

deleting all the Keys in that shutdown function using references in Hash table.

If key is stored in Key store, I am removing specific Key handle from hash table so that it won't get deleted in shutdown function

Comment: I don't fully agree. Depending on the HSM, there are many HSM providors who provide a JCE plugin giving complete compatibility when it comes to unit testing against the standard JCE and running in live against a real HSM. If you want to be JCE compatible, you do loose some functionality of the HSM. In a good soft-JCE, 'keys' are always handles rather then actual data values for example, in the Android JCE implementation using TEE's Hardware key store.